# SQL create view with multiple restrictions and subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following schema:
[image]

I am creating a view that will show properties that are for sale (l.AskingPrice is not Null and l.SaleDate is Null) and the potential buyers. A buyer is interested in a property if it has the exact number of rooms match, asking price less than or equal to the maximum price of the buyer and is located in a city the buyer is interested in. Properties where no buyer is interested should be listed with all the buyer information NULL.

The SQL I wrote is this:

```
CREATE VIEW PropertiesAndBuyers as
       SELECT DISTINCT PropertyID = property.PropertyID,
              BuyerID = (
                         SELECT BuyerID 
                           FROM Buyer 
                          WHERE property.NumberOfRooms = b.NumberOfRooms 
                                AND l.AskingPrice <= b.MaximumPrice 
                                AND bc.City = adr.City
                         ),
              Name = person.Name
         FROM Property property
              JOIN Address adr on adr.AddressID = property.AddressID
              JOIN Listing l on l.PropertyID = property.PropertyID
              JOIN Agent a on a.AgentID = l.AgentID
              JOIN Person person on person.PersonID = a.AgentID
              JOIN Buyer b on b.PersonID = person.PersonID
              JOIN BuyerCity bc on bc.BuyerID = b.BuyerID
        WHERE l.AskingPrice IS NOT NULL 
              AND l.SaleDate IS NULL
```

So the problems I am experiencing are:

Is this the write way to do it?

If it is I have i have only one property returned. I need them all back

How would I add the restriction "Properties where no buyer is interested should be listed with all the buyer information NULL"

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: The subquery will explode on you when there are multiple matches. What do you want to happen in this case? I think you are having trouble writing the query because you don't have thought enough about what you want to happen in all corner cases (especially multiple matches). Why aren't you using the Offer table at all? It seems that this table is linking Buyer and Property.

Comment: I think I will display all properties with different buyers. They may be no offers yet

Comment: case when property.NumberOfRooms = b.NumberOfRooms 
                                AND l.AskingPrice <= b.MaximumPrice 
                                AND bc.City = adr.City then BuyerID else null end as BuyerID

Comment: That kind of help but i still get 1 record only, I should get all the properties...